# Como puedo contar los digitos repetidos de un numero en javascript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo contar los digitos repetidos de un numero introducido en un prompt en javascript?

Es decir, me piden que cuando el usuario introduzca el numero en el prompt determine cuantas veces el numero "1" se repite en dicho numero y si no hay numero "1" decir que no hay.

Si alguien me pudiera explicar como hacerlo seria de mucha ayuda.

PD: disculpen mi ignorancia!

Comment: ¿Qué debería ocurrir si hay más de 1 número repetido? Por ejemplo, con la cadena 1122.

Comment: Osea el ejercicio me pide que cuente cuantas veces se repite el numero 1 y si el numero que introdujo el usuario no hay numerous 1 que le diga que no hay.

Comment: Hola @Elvis bienvenido al sitio. Por favor indica más sobre el problema. Existen muchísimas formas de hacer lo que solicitas, sin embargo tu pregunta luce como una petición del tipo "por favor alguien resuelva mi problema". Edita tu pregunta y muestra las dificultades que tienes para resolver esto, de lo contrario la pregunta será cerrada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que no es un problema "real" sino un ejercicio de bucles, en ese caso supongo que la respuesta que se esperan se parece a esto:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<div id=out></div>
<script>
    var entrada=prompt("Introduce datos");
    var busqueda="1";
    var contador=0;
    for (var i=0; i<entrada.length; i++) if (entrada[i]==busqueda) contador++;
    var respuesta;
    if (contador==0) respuesta="No se ha encontrado '"+busqueda+"'.";
    else if (contador==1) respuesta="'"+busqueda+"' se ha encontrado 1 vez.";
    else respuesta="'"+busqueda+"' se ha encontrado "+contador+" veces.";
    out.innerHTML = respuesta;
</script>
```

La idea es que, la entrada se considera un "string" donde se trata como un array de carácteres, de manera que solo hay que recorrer todas sus posiciones contando cuantas veces aparece el caracter buscado.
En problemas "reales" es mas corto y útil usar regex.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un REGEX para este propósito, por ejemplo:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Encuentra coincidencias en una cadena de caracteres.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">calcula</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = prompt("Introduce un numero", "");

    if (str != null) {
       alert("en "+ str +" el numero 1 se repite " + cuenta(str) +" veces."); 
    }
}

function cuenta(str) {  
str = str.replace(/[^1]/g, "").length  
return str;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Este ejemplo introduces un string y te mostrara cuantos "1" se encuentran en el texto que introduces:

> en 13211 el numero 1 se repite 3 veces.

Si deseas buscar cualquier numero (o carácter) puedes recibir mediante un prompt el numero donde se desea buscar y en otro el que deseas buscar, ya que puedes crear tu REGEX de acuerdo a lo que deseas buscar:

```
<script>

var coincidencia;

function myFunction() {
    var str = prompt("Introduce una cadena:", "");
    coincidencia = prompt("Introduce el caracter a buscar:", "");

    if (str != null) {
       alert("en "+ str +" el numero " + coincidencia + " se repite " + cuenta(str) +" veces."); 

    }
}

function cuenta(str) {  
var regex = new RegExp("[^"+ coincidencia +"]","g");
str = str.replace(regex, "").length  
return str;
}

</script>
```

Agrego **[el ejemplo aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/skusmd3w/5/)**.